# Sync Computers Using Ubuntu One without the Cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, file-sharing, dropbox, cloud

I am looking for a way that I can synchronize the files on two computers (assuming both run Ubuntu) WITHOUT uploading the files to the cloud as Ubuntu One does. Windows Live Mesh does this natively (I can synchronize essentially as many files/folders as I want, and pick and choose which of these I actually want "backed up" to the online cloud). So essentially, with Windows Live Mesh, I can synchronize a large amount of data (I currently sync something like 30gb) between two computers, while only something like 1Gb actually gets loaded to the cloud.

Is there a way to do this with Ubuntu One or even Ubuntu in general?

It seems a shame that Ubuntu One should be limited to being able to do nothing more than any other fileshare program (like Dropbox) can.

Answer (score 2):

This is not **yet** a feature of Ubuntu One, but it is coming in 11.10 (from what I read).

However, you could try [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/). It is a little more involving than other solutions, but it will allow you to sync between computers on a network if you set it up correctly.

> *BTW as a tip, try to avoid ranting (in other words, talking a lot **around** the subject at hand without actually making a point/asking a concrete question) when asking on this site. It is not a blog.*

Answer (score 1):

Unison would serve your purpose if you plan to sync over a LAN and it is manual only. Also, it should be a bit faster for larger transfers than Ubuntu1.

Automation and syncing over the internet will take some additional configuration.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

By the way, I too want something like Silver Spoon or Windows Live Mesh for Linux...